# Validate a disabled select2 field with jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

In my project I use jquery validate plugin for validate my form.
In this form for the select elements I use select2 plugin.
Now I tried to validate a disabled select2 field but with no success.

HTML

```
<select name="number" disabled>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('select').select2({
    allowClear: true
});

$("#form").validate({
    ignore: '',
    rules: {
        number: { required: true }
    }
});
```

How would I do that? thanks

Comment: If you disable a field, the value won't be sent when the form is submitted. If the value won't be sent, there is no need to validate the field. Why are you disabling the field?

Comment: I enable/disabled the field dinamically. I'd like to alert (validate error) only if the field is disabled because it is required in the form

Comment: You need an `<option>` that contains `value=""`.  Otherwise, the `select` will **always** pass the `required` rule, so there is nothing for validation to do here.